# JSON AFNetworking iOS 6 see if value is "on"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am trying to check if a JSON value is "on" or "off" and then perform an action with it:

```
-(IBAction)turnon {
    NSURL *api = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://app-content.co.uk/api/example.json"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:api];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    self.getinfo = [JSON objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Rapid reply: %@", JSON);
    } failure:nil];

    NSDictionary *getDB= [self.getinfo objectAtIndex:0];

    [operation start];

    if([[getDB objectForKey:@"50min_1"] isEqualToString:@"on"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Works");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Doesn't work");
    }
}
```

My JSON file looks like the following:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "50min_1": "on",
        "50min_2": "on",
        "50min_3": "on",
        "50min_4": "on",
        "50min_5": "on",
        "50min_6": "on",
        "50min_7": "on",
        "50min_8": "on"
      }
   ]
}
```

Everything looks fine if I say so, however NSLog always report "Doesn't work" which means it doesn't get the right value from the JSON file, although the server has the value on.

`NSLog(@"Rapid reply: %@", JSON);` replies the JSON file as it should.
What am I missing?

Comment: If you inspect the returned NSDictionary in the debugger, what do you see?

Comment: @middaparka If I `NSLog(@"%@", [getDB description]);` It returns `(null)` which is strange since the code should put contents in the Dictionary if I'm not mistaking?

Comment: You'll save the time if you use the actual debugger rather than debugging via NSLog. (It'll also show you the data/types in the dictionary in recent versions of Xcode.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simple - you are trying to process the results of an asynchronous operation long before the operation has completed.

Move your `if` statement into the completion block.

And a suggestion - do not pass `nil` for the failure block. At a minimum you should provide a block that logs whatever error you get.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been looking into this a couple of days and it was easier than I thought. Ofcourse `nil` was just temporary I will log/alert it in production! Thank you once again!

Comment: @AaronBrager I will, says I have to wait 3 minutes.